# Color() arguments in ggplot are interfering

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add 3 regression lines to my plot: one for all my data, and 2 for subgroups. But subgroup legends (gr1 & gr2) appear as values of `color` in the legend.

```
set.seed(18)
data <- data.frame( 
    x = sample(seq(from=0, to=4, by=0.1), 100, replace=T),
    y = sample(seq(from=0, to=4, by=0.15), 100, replace=T),
    severity = sample.int(20, 100, replace=T),
    group = sample(c("gr1", "gr2"), 100, replace=T))
```

This is how my plot is set up:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=as.factor(severity)))+
    geom_smooth(method="lm", data=data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", data=data, aes(x, y, color=group)) +
    labs(x="x", y="y", color="title")
```

[image]

I'd like to have the subgroups as separate, explanatory legends (separate from the legend of `color=as.factor(severity)`), and preferably with pre-determined colours. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding more values to the same color scale so they appear in the same legend. My solution is to duplicate the data first to add another group for the entire data so that one `geom_smooth()` is enough, and use `fill` for the `geom_point()` with a `shape` that allows filling to get a separate legend.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(18)
data <- data.frame( 
  x = sample(seq(from=0, to=4, by=0.1), 100, replace=T),
  y = sample(seq(from=0, to=4, by=0.15), 100, replace=T),
  severity = sample.int(20, 100, replace=T),
  group = sample(c("gr1", "gr2"), 100, replace=T))

data2 <- data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% # I like tibbles
  mutate(group = "gr_all") %>% 
  bind_rows(data)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = severity %>% as.factor()), shape = 21) +
  geom_smooth(data = data2, aes(color = group), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "gray10", "gray5")) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", fill = "title")
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem. Your solution works, thanks! :) Although simply adding fill=group to geom_smooth() solved my problem (without the tibble, but I see your point).

Answer (score 0):

The dummy solution could be like this

```
 set.seed(18)
data <- data.frame( 
  x = sample(seq(from=0, to=4, by=0.1), 100, replace=T),
  y = sample(seq(from=0, to=4, by=0.15), 100, replace=T),
  severity = sample.int(20, 100, replace=T),
  group = sample(c("gr1", "gr2"), 100, replace=T))


ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", data=data, aes(x, y), lty = 2, col = "black") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", data=data, aes(x, y, fill=group, lty = group), se = F) +
  labs(x="x", y="y", color="title") +
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=as.factor(severity)))
```